# List filter in Java8 using isPresent method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have one list which contains some String values. I want to iterate the list comparing with another String. Only if another String doesn't match with any element in the list, then I should enter the loop. I tried something like below, but it didn't worked. Any other alternate approach to do the same in Java 8?

Note: In the loop I'm adding some more elements to the same list. Hence, to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`, I'm using a if-condition for my validation.

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
mylist.add("test");
mylist.add("test1");

if(mylist.stream()
        .filter(str -> !(str.equalsIgnoreCase("test")))
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("Value is not Present");
}
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong: it tests if at least one element of the list is different from "test". Use `Stream.noneMatch()`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: The *using isPresent method* in the title really makes this [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Look in the link to see how you can improve your next questions on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `Stream#noneMatch` for this. It will make your code more readable and more concise. Also, try to avoid putting to much logic inside of your if statement, extract a max in readable variables

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
mylist.add("test");
mylist.add("test1");

Predicate<String> equalsIgnoreCasePredicate = str -> str.equalsIgnoreCase("test");
boolean noneMatchString = mylist.stream().noneMatch(equalsIgnoreCasePredicate);

if (noneMatchString) {
    System.out.println("Value is not Present");
}
```

Comment: I don’t think that there’s “too much logic” inside the `if` statement when you say `if(mylist.stream().noneMatch(str -> str.equalsIgnoreCase("test")))`; actually, it’s the creation of the additional variables that make it look like being much code.

Comment: @Holger I personally don't care about how many lines of code, I care about time invested in debugging and re-reading code when needed. It it can be readable and shorter, be it. But the if statement wasn't directly readable.

Comment: The original statement wasn’t, but `mylist.stream().noneMatch(str -> str.equalsIgnoreCase("test"))` says more about what is actually tested than `noneMatchString`. The latter would require rereading more code.

Comment: @Holger Fair enough

Answer (score 9):

You should use [`noneMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
if (mylist.stream().noneMatch(str -> str.equalsIgnoreCase(testString))) {
    System.out.println("Value is not Present");
}
```

Comment: Correct. No need for `filter`, `findFirst` nor the low-level `isPresent` here.

Comment: Or, using a method reference: `mylist.stream().noneMatch(testString::equalsIgnoreCase)`.

Answer (score -1):

The above can be achieved without using the `Stream` API. Below is a possible solution

```
String searchValue = "COW";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("CAT", "DOG");

if(!list.contains(searchValue)){
    System.out.println("Value is not Present");
}
```

Comment: Hard to make work with `equalsIgnoreCase`. Otherwise a good thought. I understand the downvote (but didn’t do it).

Comment: Agreed .. I missed that requirement here .. Thanks for the feedback.